# Ignore windows hidden files when copying with rsync

Tags: windows, rsync, file-transfer, files

I need to keep in sync a very large directory structure (a few hundreds GB) between a Windows machine and a Linux machine. I'm using rsync to do the copy because it automatically ignores unchanged files and is more effective at copying changed files (copying only the difference).

The problem I have is that some applications running on the Windows file system like to generate all kinds of metadata files that I don't want to copy. As all these files are hidden using Windows file attributes, I thought it would be very helpful to simply instruct rsync to ignore such files. But the rsync man page does not offer any such option.

Currently I mount the Windows file system using SMB. When I use a console to list the files in the directory (using `ls -l`), it lists all the files including hidden files, but when I use nautilus to list the files it recognizes that some are hidden files and only shows them to me if I enable "show hidden files". So I'm not sure if rsync can even see that Windows files are hidden.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the DOS attributes into Linux you will need to edit your smb.conf file.

There are two different ways to import Windows attributes.

The first option is to set `map hidden = yes` which will mean that hidden files on Windows will have the world execute bit set on Linux.  For this to work you must also have at least `001` in your `create mask`.

The other option is to set `store dos attributes = yes` which will mean that the Windows attributes will be stored in an extended attribute in the Linux file system called user.DOSATTRIB.

`rsync` doesn't have the ability to filter files based on either normal or extended attributes but it can exclude a list of files that you have prepared in some other way.  You can use the `find` command to create this list based on Unix attributes.  The version of `find` I have doesn't seem to support extended attributes but it might still be possible to use the `-exec` option in `find` to get extended attributes of all your files and filter on them.

Since `find` can filter on normal Unix permissions, if you chose the world execute bit option then `find . -perm -001` will find all of the hidden files in your mounted Windows filesystem.  You can put this list in a file and then use `rsync --exclude-from=FILE` to exclude those files from your rsync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I currently use gvfs to mount the remote system, which does not have that option, but your answer is the most detailed and will probably apply to many other situations. I will possibly switch to Samba so I can use your solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe rsync has any insight into which files are marked "Hidden" on the Windows fileshare.  Do the files have anything else in common, such as a naming format?  You can use the --exclude or --exclude-from options to pattern-match filenames not to copy.  (The --exclude-from=xyz option loads these exceptions from a file, whereas the --exclude option specifies them on the command line.)

Comment: Currently I use --exclude, but the list is rather long and its cumbersome to manage (even in a separate file). I think the "hidden file" semantics is made available through the SMB mount because Nautilus handles them perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you, but I don't think rsync is the right place to be looking.  I would either try to find something in the sharing options on the windows side, or a mount.cifs options.

It might be possible using ACL extensions, but there is nothing in traditional unix permissions that makes a file hidden.  It is just hidden if has a period as the first character in the file / dir name.

Comment: Changing things on the Windows side is not really doable (otherwise I would have just gone and deleted the files before the transfers). I don't want to make files hidden - just understand how I can tell that they are, as I mentioned some application on the Linux side can tell the difference somehow.